# How to exclude specific css files from default rules defined in Rails Webpacker config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have an issue integrating CKEditor in my rails webpacker project...
But the issue is solved by this

[CKEditor Vue Issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/issues/24)

Basically I have this rules in my environment.js

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/,
                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/[\w-/]+\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            singleton: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                            },
                            minify: true
                        } )
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I have to use two specific loader for CSS and SVG.

But CSS files and SVG files are also compiled by webpacker, and so the issue.

```
static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .vue
    - .erb
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg
```

How can I exclude css and svg files from default rules defined in Rails' Webpack config?

Comment: did you end up figuring out a way to do this? I have the same need.

Comment: I solved this specific issue... but i dont remember how. I check